# 108 Rep, but only earned 8

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, stackexchange

I'm not sure if this is simple for the SO/SE dev team, or if you moderators can do something about it.

I've got plenty of rep on SO, but don't know too much about Linux. (Surely my 100 points should count towards this?)

**However**, I *can* answer [I cannot set up dual monitors to work with 11.10 using amdcccle 11.9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66928/i-cannot-set-up-dual-monitors-to-work-with-11-10-using-amdcccle-11-9), which would seem to be of much benefit to the community.

(And having now sorted out my monitors, I've not much time to figure out other linux problems...)

Answer (score 10):

The 100 extra rep come (as you probably know) from joining in another site from the Stack Exchange network. Still those do not count when facing a protected question as the one you linked.

Protected questions require that a user gains at least 10 rep on his own before posting any answer in to it. You need to get 2 more rep from somewhere. Maybe a upvote on something you did on the site?

There you go, problem solved. Next time you can also just join the [general chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ask for some help about it.

If its useful its valuable and we will help of course.

Comment: The rep threshold for protected questions is just 10 - we don't check where it came from.  But you're entirely correct on how Stephen earned the extra 100!

Comment: @JarrodDixon just to make it clear then, what the OP is experiencing is a bug? The 100 mercy rep points he already got should count towards the protected questions requirements?

Comment: No, there is no bug.  The 100 point new account creation bonus when you have at least 200 rep on another site is no different than rep you earn from upvotes.